# C Grading Program: Not Returning 'C' for Grading Program

Tags: c

I am unsure what's wrong with my program at the moment. I can get correct values for A, B, D, F; but it does not return value C when the grade is between 70 and 80.

I understand that I went around this program a weird way, that is due to how the professor has set up the assignment. I was able to get C with simple if statements. I believe the problem has to do with how my else (userGrade B) is set up.

```
/* Jon Hays
   Assignment 3B Due 9/25/19
   "Grade Calculator"
   This program calculates the average grade (%)
   out of three test scores and converts it to a character
   (A, B, C, D, F)*/

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double test1;
    double test2;
    double test3;
    char userGrade;

    printf("Please input three test scores:");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &test1, &test2, &test3);

    double testAverage = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
    double second3rdAverage = (test2 + test3) / 2;

    if (testAverage >= 90)
        userGrade = 'A';
    else if (testAverage >= 70 && testAverage < 90)
    {
        if (test3 > 90) 
            userGrade = 'A';
        else 
            userGrade = 'B';
    }
    else if (testAverage >= 50 && testAverage < 70)
    {
        if (second3rdAverage >= 70)
            userGrade = 'C';
        else
            userGrade = 'D';
    }
    if (testAverage <= 50)
        userGrade = 'F';

    printf("%c", userGrade);
}
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but I'm still a bit lost.

this is what I was given:
"• If the average score is 90% or more, the grade is A.
• If the average score is 70% or more and less than 90%, check the third score.  If the third score is more than 90%, the grade is A; otherwise the grade is B.
• If the average score is 50% or more and less than 70%, check the average of the second and third scores.  If the average of the two is greater than 70%, the grade is C; otherwise the grade is D.
• If the average score is less than 50% then the grade is F."

Comment: Post sample values for test1, test2, test3 which you expect to return C.

Comment: In that case, did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: A side note - you don't need the "&& testAverage <" parts, they will always be true otherwise you wouldn't get to that check.

Comment: If the sample values were 70, 71, and 70, it should return C. However it always returns B. But, if I type 60, 61, and 60 I return value D; so at least that branch is right.

Comment: You can add `printf( "testAverage = %lf, second3rdAverage = %lf\n", testAverage, second3rdAverage );` after their calculation for diagnostic.

Comment: With sample values 70, 71, and 70; second3rdAverage = 70.5, so I would think it should return value C.

Comment: @J.J.Hays With 70, 71, 70 the value of `testAverage` is 70.3333 and you cannot pass `testAverage < 70` condition.

Comment: @J.J.Hays "_With sample values 70, 71, and 70; second3rdAverage = 70.5, so I would think it should return value C._" But, what is the value of `testAverage`? Since, the value of it drives the outer `if`s.

Comment: try with 50 70 and 75, it should give the C

Comment: You only use `second3rdAverage` when `testAverage` is between 50 and 70. It doesn't matter when `testAverage = 70.333`

Comment: The value of testAverage is 70.3333, as @i486 said this would not pass. I have edited the code and can now get value "C" for test scores 30, 70, and 70. However, this doesn't really make sense as if you had 3 test scores of 30 70 and 70, the grade average would be a D and not a C. Perhaps the instructions for the assignment are confusing, or I am confused. Not sure which at this point.

Comment: You should have an "else" before the "if (testAverage <= 50)" otherwise you set userGrade twice when testAverage == 50.

Comment: OT:  nothing in the header file: `math.h` is being used by the OPs program.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct. The task you indicated in the comments

> - If the average score is 90% or more, the grade is A.
> - If the average score is 70% or more and less than 90%, check the third score.
>
>   - If the third score is more than 90%, the grade is A; otherwise the grade is B.
> - If the average score is 50% or more and less than 70%, check the average of the second and third scores.
>
>   - If the average of the two is greater than 70%, the grade is C; otherwise the grade is D.
> - If the average score is less than 50% then the grade is F.

means, that a C is only awarded if your overall score is below 70%. I guess, your assumption was, that the task at hand has something to do with real grading - which is not the case.

Comment: Yes, this was the error. I thought I was wrong, but it turned out I was right. Solved, thanks for the clarification.